# jQuery 1.7.2: attr('src') returns undefined on server but works fine locally

Tags: jquery, undefined, attr

On my page I have an element

```
<img id='image123' src='http://server.de/image.png' />
```

of what I want to get the src-attribute via jQuery.

I try this with the statement

```
alert($('#image123').attr('src'));
```

which works locally in my xampp server (prompting http://server.de/image.png) but not on my webserver. There I only get the alert popup with text 'undefined'

With Firebug I can debug to the line of code without getting an error, so jQuery seems to work.

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance for your help!

EDIT: [RESOLVED] as I can't answer my own question I post my solution up here:

**Thanks for all responses**, I found the error. The id 'image123' was concatenated like 'image'+id where id was the function parameter (holding 123). For some reasons on my server I did not get 123 but 12300 with some zeros at the end. When I pass the 123 as a string to my function everything works as expected. **Thanks for your help!**

Comment: is jQuery present in your webserver? Since you are using different servers, please check

Comment: Is the script trying to run before the HTML is loaded?

Comment: The method is triggered by a mouse over event, so HTML should be there. As I can debug the code and it passes an if statement (`code`if($('#image123')`code`) jQuery seems to be present)

Answer (score 1):

try it like this

```
$(function(){
alert($('#image123').attr('src'));
});
```

Comment: +1 Yep, sounds like the image doesn't exist when the selector runs.

Comment: This returns undefined as well

Comment: The image I try to load comes from another server...so this is the same for my project locally or on my webserver. If I copy the url out of the image tag and paste it into the browser the image can be loaded.

Comment: the image url need not to be necessarily valid. still you should get the path

Comment: `Coming from another server`?  Are you using `ajax` to pull something in?  If so, you'll have to handle the asynchronous timing.